# Jenkins Integration with .net c++ project

Tags: .net, jenkins, plugins, msbuild

I am trying to build set up jenkins for visual studio project on c++ language.
but after build it's showing me this error :

```
MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: D:\Department\project_code\Project
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked 
build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can you please tell me why this error is accruing. And how can i solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show us the reference to your project from jenkins build settings? You need to reference straight to `.vcxproj`?

In settings set `MSBuild build file` for path to `.vcxproj` like `Test\Test1\Test1.vcxproj`.

Comment: MSBuild Build File -> In this section do i need to add path of MSBuild.exe or path of the source code project.vcxproj?

Answer (score 0):

Now i found solution of error :

MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: D:\Department\project_code\Project
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked 
build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

For solve this error i need to follow following steps:

1. First set MSBuild.exe location into Global tool's MSBuild section in jenkins.
2. In project i need to select MSBuild (i.e MSBuild.exe).
3. The location of my project ->"C:\project_folder\project.sln"
4. Apply and Save.
   :)